# Adjusting Sum of Divs by turning input button On & Off

Tags: jquery, html

(I am simplifying my table but) I have a table where each row has an on/off button (id='b1') and a price column (amount preset in html div, class='plus'); there are four prices in the table now but more or less may need to be coded in. At the bottom of the table, the final row has a total cell and all the numbers in the div with the class name plus get added together and the total is displayed.

My question is, I need to be able to reflect changes in the total when the on and off button beside the price is change. (If it is off then the price should not be included in the total and if it is on it should be).

Here is the function I had written but it doesn't work:

```
$('#b1').click(function (){
    console.log('test'); 

        if(('#b1').val('OFF')){
           $(this).closest('td').children('div.plus').val(0); 
        } else if(('#b1').val('ON')){
            // do nothing
            console.log('do nothing');
        }
    });
```

Here is the html for two rows:

```
<tr class="ui-state-default">
                            <td>Additional One</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="multiple sub location" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-title="Enter username">Additional One</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form action="">
                                    <input type="button" class='secondA' id="b1" value="ON">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <td>$</td>
                            <td><div class='plus'>9.99</div></td>
                            <td><input type="number" class="minus" value=""/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="ui-state-default">
                            <td>Additional Two</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="multiple sub location" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-title="Enter username">Additional Two</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form action="">
                                    <input type="button" class='secondA' id="b1" value="ON">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <td>$</td>
                            <td><div class='plus'>8.99</div></td>
                            <td><input type="number" class="minus" value=""/></td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work."

Comment: Nothing happens when I turn the button off, the total column is not adjusted. The console.log('test'); does not run either but I ran a console.log('test'); in the rest of my code and it runs fine. I am just thinking.. would I need to add a button to update total so when the on/off button is changed the button can be clicked to notify the jquery to run and make changes? Ideally, I would like it to dynamically update without the button but not sure how that would work

Comment: You have a few typos in your code. `('#b1')` should be `$('#b1')`, and when that's fixed you're doing the comparison incorrectly. `if(('#b1').val('OFF'))` should be `if($('#b1').val()=='OFF')` and the same for on. Also, `.closest('td')` won't work with `.children('div.plus')` becuase you're not going up high enough in the DOM. `.closest('tr')` should work.

Comment: each row CAN'T have an input with id="b1" because id's can't exist more than once in a document.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I changed my code as per j08691 but still didn't work. Also changed id to class so it could be used on multiple buttons as per bpeterson76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, you shouldn't use the same `id=""` attribute twice. However, the buttons classes will do. try this:

To show the sum, add a row to your table

```
<tr>
  <td class="total"></td>
</tr>
```

Then elaborate your click function:

```
$(function(){

  var sum = $('.total');
  var product = $('.ui-state-default');
  var button = $('.ui-state-default input[type="button"]');

  $(button).on('click', function() {
    var total = 0;
    if ($(this).attr('value') == 'OFF') {
      $(this).attr('value', 'ON');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('value', 'OFF');
    }
    button.each(function(){
      if ($(this).attr('value') == 'ON') {
        total += parseFloat($(this).parents('tr').find('.plus').text());  
      }
    });
    sum.text(total);
  });
});
```

1) Initialize your total.

2) Handle the value of your buttons.

3) Iterate through your rows, to sum up a total price using `parseFloat(StringValue)`.

Maybe you'll figure out how to change the sum when adjusting the quantity with your other `<input>`s.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xq4aky2t/2/).

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed! I appreciate the fiddle as well :)